# $x^4-x^3+x^2-(c+1)x-(c^2-c)=0$ has solution $ \alpha $, then value of $c=\alpha^2-\alpha$.

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, roots

Let $c$ be positive real number for which equation $x^4-x^3+x^2-(c+1)x-(c^2-c)=0$ has real solution $\alpha$. Prove that $c=\alpha^2-\alpha$.
Since $\alpha $ is solution than $\alpha^4-\alpha^3+\alpha^2-(c+1)\alpha-(c^2-c)=0$

$c^2+c(1+\alpha)+\alpha-\alpha^2+\alpha^3-\alpha^4=0$

solving for $c$, $-(1+\alpha)\pm \sqrt{((1+\alpha)^2-4(\alpha-\alpha^2+\alpha^3-\alpha^4))}$
but this doesn't help.

**Edit** There is some problem in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim is not true.  For example let
$$c=\frac{-1+\sqrt{41}}{2}\ .$$
Then the equation is
$$x^4-x^3+x^2-\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{2}x-(11-\sqrt{41})=0\ ,$$
which has solution $2$ (among others).  But $c$ is not equal to $2^2-2$.

Comment: Albeit it's true that there exists a solution $\alpha$ satisfying $c=\alpha^2-\alpha$.

Comment: Perhaps that's what OP meant.  If so, they need to edit the question.

Comment: @David wording of question is almost same from where I picked it, they have asked to proof it,  so i assume statement is true in place. After seeing your counter example I'm confused.

Comment: @saurabhrana perhaps you should ask the source to clarify the question, and point out that it is not true the way they have asked it.